# Nested loop rectangle *Makes a rectangle with different letters on each line*

Tags: loops, nested, alphabet

The output should be

```
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFF
GGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHH
IIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJ
```

My code is this:

```
        char let = 65;
        for (int i = 0;i < 10; i ++)
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < 10; x ++)
           {
              System.out.print(let);
           }
           System.out.println();
           let++;
        }
```

I know im very close but what am i doing wrong i cant seem to figure this out

Comment: the output should be above each other in different lines so that it forms a rectangle

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry my mistake. Your code should work.

Comment: Why would you need to cast a char to a char? Java already knows that `let` is a `char`, no need to cast it.

Comment: Oh yeah I just looked it up and you're correct. I assumed it was displaying the values as ints since it does the same with other primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way (while + for loop):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int RECT_WIDTH  =  9;
    final int RECT_HEIGHT = 10;

    final char BEGIN_LETTER = 'A';

    char currentLetter = BEGIN_LETTER;
    while ((currentLetter - BEGIN_LETTER) < RECT_HEIGHT) {
        for (int column=0; column<RECT_WIDTH; column++) {
            System.out.print(currentLetter);
        }
        System.out.println();
        currentLetter++;
    }

}
```

There are many more ways to achieve the same result. 2 nested for loops, ...